# Swift - Cast Any IntegerType to Int

Tags: swift

Is there any easy way to convert Any IntegerType to Int in Swift. I have a dictionary which contains different types of integers; UInt8, UInt16 etc. and need to convert this to Int. Is there any easier way apart of switch statement:

```
let x: UInt8 = 5
let any: Any = x

var size: Int
switch (any) {
case let value as Int8:   size = Int(value)
case let value as UInt8:  size = Int(value)
case let value as Int16:  size = Int(value)
case let value as UInt16: size = Int(value)
case let value as Int32:  size = Int(value)
case let value as UInt32: size = Int(value)
case let value as Int64:  size = Int(value)
case let value as UInt64: size = Int(value)
case let value as Int:    size = Int(value)
case let value as UInt:   size = Int(value)
default: size = 0
}
```

Comment: You can always use hashValue property from any IntegerType

Comment: This may work but how do I convert Any to IntegerType?

Comment: if let int = (any as? UInt8)?.hashValue  {
    print(int)
}

Comment: so this would be the switch statement I've wrote :-) I'm not aware with which type I'm dealing with so I need to test for all possible types

Comment: Why don't you use Int when storing your values in your dictionary?

Comment: I'm writing binary parser class and would like to achieve something like https://github.com/keichi/binary-parser or https://github.com/substack/node-binary but in Swift. I can't use Int only 64-bit unsigned would not fit. I can consider to use Int or UInt but I consider to add "reverse" feature later, so convert dictionary to binary. And I'm trying to learn Swift in the same time :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you allowed `Any` to come into the picture. At that point, you lose a lot of power.

The other problem you're facing is that your code as written is poorly defined and Swift resists you writing code that way (basically by forcing you to be explicit). If you are passed a UInt64, there is no guarantee that `size` will have the same value as `value`. This is a very common problem when people seek an automatic way to convert between number types. Swift encourages you to think about numeric conversions because they are a common source of bugs.

There are several things you can do depending on what you're trying to solve. If you want a data structure that holds either an Int64 or a UInt64, that's easy. Just create the type you mean.

```
enum ParsedNumber {
    case Signed(Int64)
    case Unsigned(UInt64)
}

let numbers: [String: ParsedNumber] = [:]
```

Then all your values will fit in that. If you need to keep track of the width for later, that's no problem either:

```
struct ParsedNumber {
    enum Value {
        case Signed(Int64)
        case Unsigned(UInt64)
    }
    let width: Int
    let value: Value
}

let n = ParsedNumber(width: 32, value: .Signed(2))
```

This feels like the problem you're solving. If on the other hand you know your type at one point (i.e. it's `Int8`, not `Any`) and just want to be able to pass it to functions, just make the functions generic on `IntegerType`:

```
func calc<Num: IntegerType>(num: Num) { ... }
```

A useful tool on `IntegerType` is its `toIntMax()` method. This will trap (crash) if the value is too large, so be aware, but it's a useful way to convert arbitrary values to a known integer type. There are also `SignedIntegerType` and `UnsignedIntegerType` if you know your sign already. (You can't convert `Any` to these, though. You need to already have a known type somewhere.)

Comment: Thank you, I take your point. I guess I can expand this idea to other types like floats, strings.

Comment: Yeah. A parser like you're discussion almost certainly wants to spit out some kind of enum that constrains its results to the types that are parseable, and packages them in a way that is convenient for the rest of your program. Remember that enums can have their own methods, so it is easy to create `isString: Bool` or `stringValue: String?` on the enum so it can be used without requiring switch statements everywhere if you don't want them.